# How can I set a List<foo> field of an object with the value of List<dynamic>

Tags: c#, database, list, dynamic, casting

I have been trying to set some field values of specific objects in C#.
For other reasons I need to construct a List of values from a string then I want to assign this to a field in an object.
The way I indicate the value type of the list is something like this in string
`name:type{listItemName:listItemType{listItemValue}}`

This list can be of any type, so it is undetermined until we reach conversion.
I am using

```
        List<dynamic> ldy = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach (string listElement in listElements)
        {
            if (listElement == "") continue;
         
            Type leDataType = GetDataType(listElement);
            string leData = GetDataRaw(listElement);

            var leDynamic = ConstructDataObject(leDataType, leData, listElement);
            ldy.Add(leDynamic);
        }
```

Which ends up with the correct data and with the correct data type when I enquire, however when I am trying to use the resulting `ldy` list and assign it to a field, of course it acts as a `List<object>`
thus not allowing me to assign.
Finally so, I am using `field.SetValue(targetObject, ldy);` to assign the value to the field.

The error message I am getting is

```
ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'.
```

Which to be clear, I do understand and I do understand why, however I dont really see how could I solve this issue, not by solving this nor by changing the fundaments of my code design.

Please help!

Comment: It seems like instead of using a `List<dynamic>` you should use reflection to create a list of the type you expect before creating the object to put into it.

Answer (score 0):

As @juharr suggested I have searched for solutions to do this with reflection.
Here is my solution:

```
    private static IList GetTypedList(Type t)
    {
        var listType = typeof(List<>);
        var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(t);
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);
        return (IList)instance;
    }
```